# Как правильно: "Такими вещами не шутят" или "С такими вещами не шутят"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "Такими вещами не шутят" или "С такими вещами не шутят"?

Answer (score 2):

Это два абсолютно разных выражения.

Выражение **"такими вещами не шутят"** употребляется в тех случаях, когда речь идет о чем-то морально значимом, с чем шутки неуместны главным образом из этических соображений.

> - Ты понимаешь, что речь идет о здоровье близкого мне человека? **Такими вещами не шутят!**

А выражение **"с такими вещами не шутят"** используется тогда, когда речь идет о чем-то потенциально опасном, неосторожное обращение с чем может привести к негативным последствиям.

> - Ты решил самостоятельно обезвредить мину ПФМ-1? Без опыта? Голыми руками? Ты что, не понимаешь, что **с такими вещами не шутят**?

Comment: Интересно, почему в Нацкорпусе нет ни одного примера предложений с выражением "с такими вещами не шутят"?

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова, мне сложно давать оценки деятельности Нацкорпуса. Просто попробуйте в примере с миной из моего ответа убрать "с" и сравните, как это будет звучать. На мой взгляд, потеряется весь смысл сказанного.

Comment: Это понятно, но выражение с предлогом (тут я согласна с shampar) - это уже свободное словосочетание с конкретным в каждом случае смыслом. Это уже не фразеологизм.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова, безусловно, но ведь автор вопроса спрашивал, как правильно писать, а не о том, являются ли оба варианта фразеологизмами. Я написал в своем ответе, что написать можно и так и так, в зависимости от конкретного случая.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

**Такими вещами не шутят.**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса (вышло 115 645 документов с выражением "такими вещами не шутят" и ни одного "с такими вещами не шутят"):

*Такими вещами не шутят, ― сказал Объедало, взглянув на Опивалу, и снова отвернулся.* [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 3) (1989)]

*Вообще-то, Слава, мама права: такими вещами не шутят.* [Владислав Крапивин. Трое с площади Карронад (1979)]

**У меня есть только предположение происхождения этого устойчивого выражения**: оно стало отголоском известного фразеологизма "*Чем ч..рт не шутит (из дубинки выпалит)?*"

А в предложенном Вами выражении смысл противоположный: есть такие вещи, которыми шутить нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли правила применимые к этому словосочетанию?

Comment: Дополнила ответ.

Answer (score 1):

«Такими вещами не шутят» — фразеологизм, фраза универсальная, практически неизменяемая и о многом. Введение предлога сводит эту фразу, по сути философскую, к несколько искажённой с непонятными мотивами кальке и необходимости дать описание тех самых «вещей» — что именно она подразумевает.

О неправильности говорить нельзя: здесь смена значимости сказанного.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру:

ШУТИТЬ 4. **(чем, с чем).** Относиться к чему-л. несерьёзно, без должного внимания, пренебрегать чем-л. Ш. своим здоровьем, со своим здоровьем. Ш. счастьем дочери не могу. Не шути с этим.

1) Такими вещами не шутят, это серьезные вещи

**Шутить этим:** творительный падеж, беспредложное управление. Здесь тесная связь глагола существительным, которое определяет само действие: придает ему известный вид, форму, образ. Это грамматический орудийный падеж.

2) С такими вещами не шутят, с ними надо обращаться осторожно

**Шутить с этим:** При наличии предлога связь ослабевает, значение предмета становится. сопроводительным, мыслится как нечто внешнее.

Answer (score 0):

Шутить можно как чем-то, так и с чем-то. Но соглашусь с теми, кто считает "такими вещами не шутят" фразеологизмом и советует *с ним не шутить* (не изменять его). В Нацкорпусе это выражение встречается только в варианте без *с*.